# On mobile submenu 'All %categoryname' is not translated - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, localisation

I can't translate the string 'All' from the subcategory on mobile menu. The file where the string appears is `menu.js` located on `public/lib/web/mage/`

And it looks like this:

```
.text($.mage.__('All ') + category);
```

So only the string 'All' needs to be translated, it doesn't require to put something like 'All %1', 'translatedAll %1' in my language file. 
The translations I made looks like this:

```
"All ", "translatedAll "
```

Also I tried to put the location for the translation, like this:

```
"All ","translatedAll ",lib,lib/web/mage/menu.js
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to translate directly in the en_US.csv file from `public/lib/web/i18n/`. Not working either

**How can I translate this?**

Comment: It's seems specific theme dependent... Have you try to change the `menu.js` file?

Comment: Translations actually have their own cache, so double check that you aren't getting tripped up there: `magento cache:clean translate` or System>Cache Management.

Comment: This is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Magento 2.3.x and 2.4.x :

Responsible file for this html is `lib/web/mage/menu.js`
You can see translatable text is "All %1".

In your `app/design/[Vendor]/[ThemeName]/i18n/en_US.csv` (change .csv file name following translation you need), add this line :

```
"All %1", "Yourtranslation %1"
```

Then run `php bin/mangento c:f` to flush cache.

Sometimes flushing the cache is not enough for js translation, you will need to delete the file js-translation.json located in `pub/static/frontend/[Vendor]/[ThemeName]/[local]/js-translation.json`

It will be regenerated when loading page.

Hope this help